# I want to filter a model but their are many filters and all aren't required django?

Tags: python, django

In my project, I want to build a filter system
and the filter is not by 1 field it is by about 6 fields but every field isn't required
but at backend I have to use many queries
like if 3 fields are coming:

```
field1 = form.field1
field2 = form.field2
field3 = form.field3
field3 = form.field4
field4 = form.field5
field5 = form.field6
if field1:
   filter_by_other_field
if field2:
   filter_by_other_field
if field1 and field2:
   filter_by_other_field
```

but by doing this method it will make many queries
so can u pls help me In this case I want to use less code
Thanks

Comment: Investigate the well-known package Django-filter https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html. It may do all you want and more. It even has a specific tag on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't make many queries, because the queryset is lazily evaluated, so it only makes the actual query when you use it ...

So you can do

```
qs = myobj.objects.all()
if field1: 
   qs = qs.filter(field1=field1)
```

Alternatively use Q objects

```
qs = Q(field1="val1")
if field2:
   qs |= Q(field2=field2)

myset = mymodel.objects.filter(qs)
```

etc.

It's only when you try and do something with the queryset, eg. take the first object with a slice, that it will get evaluated.